# Porting from pcl-1.5 to pcl-1.7

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, point-cloud-library

I am using `ubuntu14.04`. I have a code which is written in `pcl-1.5`. I now want to run it in `pcl-1.7`. It's giving a lot of compilation errors.
Is there a way to port my classes and functions from `pcl-1.5` to `pcl-1.7`?

Comment: Do you want to ask if it is possible to install pcl-1.5 on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: I want to run `pcl-1.5` code with `pcl-1.7` installed.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to build your project on PCL 1.5 while PCL 1.7 is installed. This is possible. I assume you install PCL 1.5 from source and then build it so that it ends up with a build directory. These instructions are vague because it has been a while since I have done this but here they are: In the project you are trying to build (I am assuming you are using cmake), put something like the following line before the line `find_package(PCL REQUIRED)` (or the similar line that you have):

`SET(PCL_DIR /path/to/pcl1.5/build CACHE LOCATION "Where the PCL version I want to use has been built to")`

---Edit based on comment---

Okay, so it seems by PCL 1.5 code you mean code that you have previously written for PCL 1.5 and want to run with PCL 1.7. This should be possible but those with a good knowledge of the main differences between 1.5 and 1.7 probably will not have the time to answer this question. As such I suggest you check the errors as they come up during compilation and running and check the new API for the new way of doing things. It will be easier to locate the errors if you compile your project bit by bit. If you understand what the code is doing it will be easier also. That is all that I have.

Comment: Please refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958491/installation-issue-in-pcl-1-5-1) question. I'm not able to install `pcl-1.5` on `Ubuntu 14.04`.