# Installation issue in pcl-1.5.1

Tags: c++, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-14.04, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to install `pcl-1.5` from the source [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/tree/pcl-1.5.1). I'm able to install it on my laptop (`Ubuntu 12.04`) but on the desktop (`Ubuntu 14.04`), it's not compiling.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

It's giving lots of errors. Check http://pastebin.com/P37L9yCm for the output in the error stream.

What's the problem?

Isn't `pcl-1.5` for `Ubuntu 14.04`? Okay! I've installed `pcl-1.7` successfully. But then how do I run my previous `pcl-1.5` code on it? Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25915607/backporting-from-pcl-1-7-to-pcl-1-5) question.

Comment: 1. The messages you have given seem to be warnings (I think) so if we can see more of the errors it might help more. If you need to, run `make` by prepending it with `VERBOSE=1` like this: `VERBOSE=1 make`.

Comment: 2. At a guess as to the main source of these problems, you could try with an older compiler. I believe 14.04 has gcc-4.6 available out of the box (via package manager, I mean). Or, you might force the compiler to behave like it used to with some switches.

Comment: 1. Update my answer. 2. I installed `gcc-4.6`. It didn't do anything.

Comment: What is the problem to upgrade your code from 1.5 to 1.7? Also, all the problems appear to be Eigen-related. Maybe your currect, newer Eigen version is not compatible with older PCL

Comment: Check out this post: http://www.pcl-users.org/errors-in-eigen-h-td4032518.html it might be useful

Comment: Also check this: http://answers.ros.org/question/76201/error-using-eigen-sqrt-while-compiling-ros-pcl/